# Is there any humanoid robot simulation working on Kinetic?

Tags: ros, simulation, nao-robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been trying out few existing packages but nothing seems to be up to date (especially for Gazebo).
[Darwin simulation](https://www.generationrobots.com/en/content/83-carry-out-simulations-and-make-your-darwin-op-walk-with-gazebo-and-ros) doesn't start correctly  and NAO needs proprietary software (Webots and Choregraph) and [REEM-C](https://github.com/pal-robotics/reemc_simulation) doesn't even compile (probably not compatible with the new Gazebo).

I just want to make something humanoid-like move arms and legs and get a bag of the joint states.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/266852/is-there-any-humanoid-robot-simulation-working-on-kinetic?/) by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on ROS Answers with karma: 3339 on 2017-07-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The package you mentioned is not official. We are offering the OP(aka “DARWIN OP”) packages below. The robotis_op3_common package provides launch files and plug-in for Gazebo and RViz.

- http://wiki.ros.org/robotis_op3_common
- http://wiki.ros.org/robotis_op3

---

Originally posted by [Pyo](https://answers.ros.org/users/632/pyo/) with karma: 358 on 2018-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0